# load and edit HTML data in RichEditBox in Windows phone

Tags: html, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, rtf

I have to load html data from the api into some control in windows phone that can enable the user to edit it as well. The data can have bullet list(ul li) or a table. I have tried the following

1. have tried to put the data in Webview and use
       CaptureSelectedContentToDataPackageAsync and then use
       DocumentPackage to get the RTF. But its not implemented in windows
       phone 8.1.
2. tried to convert html to RTF. but could not convert table and list.

how can I achieve loading and editing the data?

Comment: Hi Ramya, have you achieved your requirement,  Even I am also in same requirement. Can you give any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a web based WYSIWYG editor locally placed in a Webview.
You can interact with it using `WebVoew.InvokeSctiptAsync()`.
This method returns whatever the requested js function returns. So you can get the text of the editor using js codes and and use it in c# with this method.